# read html nodes in r

Tags: r

I need toget a set of vector from the the internet which is available in html format.

I'm reading the webpage this way:

```
add=url
doc=htmlTreeParse(add)
```

This how doc looks:

> doc
>         $file
>         [1] "http://ifis.iowafloodcenter.org/ifis/ifis5/ws/objects.php?id=741&type=4"

```
  $version
  [1] ""

  $children
  $children$html
  <html>
  <body>
  <p>743,762,754,759,761,744,741,755,758,742,757,716,760</p>
  </body>
 </html>


  attr(,"class")
 [1] "HTMLDocument"
```

I wish to obtain numbers under

as vector.

I tried using :

```
xmlValue(xmlRoot(doc) )
```

But this does not give me vector.

How can it be done?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is it:

```
getURL(add,encoding = "iso8859-8") 
v2=strsplit(v, "\\,")
as.numeric(v2[[1]][[2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
 `getURL(add)`
```

from RCurl package

Comment: I tried using that too. It gives me this:
[1] "743,762,754,759,761,744,741,755,758,742,757,716,760"
which is not a vector

Comment: But you can then convert it into vector :unlist(strsplit(try,","))